# What is the best way to do background tasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am studying Android (Java) and until then performed my background tasks using `AsyncTask`.

```
public class SuaClasse extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Integer>{
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute(){
    //Codigo
  }
  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    //Codigo
  }
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Integer numero){
    //Codigo
  }
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer… params){
    //Codigo
  }

}
```

I recently read that this may not be the best way, and that `AsyncTask` tends to become obsolete soon ... something about `RxJava` has been quoted.

Is that true?

I would like to know what are the ways to do background tasks, what are the the details of each and, if any, what is the best way.

Comment: Hi, the best replace for AsyncTask is Kotlin Coroutines :D, check about that

Answer (score 0):

RxJava is a really good way to handle background tasks in Android. It makes handling background thread easier. You don't have to worry about error handling which for me makes it even better. I am also learning this RxJava 2 and I fall in love with it ever time. [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)  is made on top of Rx java. [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html) you can learn basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Background Services` with `WorkManager`. This is part of android `JetPack`. Explore it more on [Official Document-best-background](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background)

`AsyncTask` Does not suits in every situation.

`Rx` Concept i specially for managing stream of events.

If your need is only to handle background task.Then using `Rx` is not recommendable.
Use Android in-built latest feature for this.

Note: Check Official document of RX too.